# Error PlanningExternalEvent.php on line 160

Tags: php

In GLP 10.0.3.

On the plan, I have this error:

`Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp64\www\glpi\src\PlanningExternalEvent.php on line 160`

My PlanningExternalEvent on line 160 :

```
        $is_rrule = strlen($this->fields['rrule']) > 0;
```

Can you help me ?
Thx

```
        $is_rrule = strlen($this->fields['rrule']) > 1;
```

Comment: From the error `$this->fields['rrule']` is obviously an array. So look closer at your data structure to work out where the data you want actually resides

Answer (score 0):

As the errors says the
`$this->fields['rrule']`

Is not string you can use
`var_dump($this->fields['rrule']);`

To check your data

Answer (score 0):

Your `$this->fields['rrule']` is not a string but an array.

If you're expecting this, please type check before getting the str_len

```
if(is_string($this->fields['rrule'])){
    $is_rrule = strlen($this->fields['rrule']) > 0;
}else if(is_countable($this->fields['rrule'])){
    $is_rrule = count($this->fields['rrule']);
}else{
    $is_rrule = false;
}
```

Alternatively, you can make sure that the field being set is in fact a string
before passing it to the function/method